# How can i Sort a List<Tuple<int, double>>

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Hello and thanks for reading this post.

I have a list that is created this way

```
List<Tuple<int, double>> Ratings = new List<Tuple<int, double>>();
```

Lets say the value of the list is as below

```
Index      int     double

[0]        1       4,5
[1]        4       1,0
[2]        3       5,0
[3]        2       2,5
```

How can I sort the list so the double value that is higgest is on top? like this

```
Index      int     double
[0]        3       5,0
[1]        1       4,5
[2]        2       2,5
[3]        4       1,0
```

Comment: `Ratings = Ratings.OrderByDescending(tuple => tuple.Item2).ToList()`?

Comment: If creating a new list is acceptable, you can simply use `.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Item2).ToList()`.

Comment: For inplace sorting you can use `list.Sort((x,y)=>Comparer<double>.Default.Compare(y.Item2,x.Item2));`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use

```
Ratings = Ratings.OrderByDescending (t => t.Item2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

```
Ratings.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2);
```

Comment: you should use the return value of OrderByDescending() to work with

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the [`Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the list, intellisense should have suggested it to you and it's kinda natural:

```
Ratings.Sort((x, y) => y.Item2.CompareTo(x.Item2));
// at this stage the Ratings list will be sorted as desired
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Tuple<int, double>> Ratings = new List<Tuple<int, double>>();

                    Ratings.Add(new Tuple<int, double>(1, 4.5));
                    Ratings.Add(new Tuple<int, double>(4, 1.0));
                    Ratings.Add(new Tuple<int, double>(3, 5.0));
                    Ratings.Add(new Tuple<int, double>(2, 2.5));

                    var list = Ratings.OrderByDescending(c => c.Item2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var comparer = Comparer<Tuple<int, double>>.Create((x, y) => -1 * x.Item2.CompareTo(y.Item2));
Ratings.Sort(comparer);
```

Comment: Multiplying by `-1` is not a good idea since it doesn't change the sign of `int.MinValue`. This is a valid return value of for comparer, even if the double comparer probably does not return that value. Swap `x` and `y` instead.

Comment: `List.Sort` has an overload that takes a `Comparison<T>` delegate, no need to construct a comparer.